# Override already configured WebMvcAdapter in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-admin

I want to extend the features of Spring Boot Admin's UI, by bootstrapping custom pages, menus etc. However, I don't want to modify SBA's JAR directly, because this would imply having to apply my modifications to it every time a new version comes out.

The approach I am currently considering is to modify HTML pages on the fly as they are rendered by the resource handlers of SBA (class `AdminServerWebConfiguration`). I would register my own resource handler in the `registry`, let SBA render it, then modify the render on the fly and finally return the result.

My understanding of how I would do such a thing is very limited. Can anyone point me to pattern to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that. If you are modifying the HTML and they change that in the the next release don't you have the same problem as with the jar? I'm not sure that this part of Boot was built to be extended, and my gut tells me this is not a way you want to travel down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the best way to modify the ui is to copy the spring-boot-admin-server-ui project, do your modifications and include your own ui-jar instead of the original one.